# Run function on custom post type array only

Tags: php, wordpress, function, hook, custom-post-type

I would like to run following code only on a given custom post types. now its running only on one specific custom type 'file' .

I tried to add the function in an array but i am quiet sure it wasn't the right thing

```html
 // For deleting attachments when Deleting POSTS
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'mtp_delete_attached_thumbnail_for_trashed_product', 20, 1 );

function mtp_delete_attached_thumbnail_for_trashed_product( $post_id ) {
 
 // gets ID of post being trashed
 $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
  

 // does not run on other post types
 if ( $post_type != 'file' ) {
 return true;
 }

 // get ID of featured image
 $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
  
 // delete featured image
 wp_delete_attachment( $post_thumbnail_id, true );

}
```

for example only if the custom post type is 'file' or 'share' or 'folder' then the featured image will be deleted when deleting the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the in_array() to simplify this.

```
// For deleting attachments when Deleting POSTS
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'mtp_delete_attached_thumbnail_for_trashed_product', 20, 1 );

function mtp_delete_attached_thumbnail_for_trashed_product( $post_id ) {

 // List of post types.
  $post_types = array(
          'file',
          'share',
          'folder',
   );

 // gets ID of post being trashed
 $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );


 // does not run on other post types
 if ( ! in_array( $post_type, $post_types, true) ) {
 return true;
 }

 // get ID of featured image
 $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );

 // delete featured image
 wp_delete_attachment( $post_thumbnail_id, true );

}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

Comment: for some reason its not working for any post type. i tried to keep only one post type and also not working.

Comment: @Nash You want to delete the featured image when the post type is either file, share or folder, isn't it?

Comment: Yes exactly. when deleting a post from post types file or share or folder, then look for feature image and delete it.

Comment: @Nash Great. Glad to help.